# Actionscript-3 and android-sqlite problem

Tags: actionscript-3, android-sqlite

i have problem when i useing this mothod : createTable.execute()!!!!!
    i had no problem in air for windows but in air for android no anny error acured but but game stoped in frame 1.
    import flash.data.SQLConnection;
    import flash.events.SQLErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.SQLEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.data.SQLStatement;
    import flash.data.SQLMode;
    import flash.data.SQLResult;
    import flash.errors.SQLError;

```
var conn: SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();

conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);
conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
// The database file is in the application storage directory
var folder: File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
var dbFile: File = folder.resolvePath("DBSave1.db");
//conn.openAsync(dbFile);
conn.openAsync(dbFile);

function openHandler(event: SQLEvent): void {
    trace("#############the database was created successfully#############");
}
function errorHandler(event: SQLErrorEvent): void {
    trace("#############Error message############# :", event.error.message);
    trace("#############Details err############# :", event.error.details);
}

trace("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
var createTable: SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
createTable.sqlConnection = conn;

var table: String = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS savegame (" + "uId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "firstParam TEXT, " + "secondParam TEXT, " + "thirdParam TEXT " + ")";

createTable.text = table;

try {
    createTable.execute();
    trace("Table created");
} catch (error: SQLError) {
    trace("Error message:", error.message);
    trace("Details:", error.details);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have to place another function in openHandler() . first we should open database and in its function do another operation related to database.